# JQuery class selectors like $(.someClass) are case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, standards, quirks-mode

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="OpenIDSelector">some text</div>
```

Why does this JQuery selector match it on some browsers and some pages, but not on others?

```
$('.OpenIdSelector')
```

*NOTE: I ran into this problem and solved it myself, but it was annoying and I didn't find it on StackOverflow already, so I'm posting it as a Q&A pair so someone else won't waste an hour like I did.*

Comment: yeah, they are case sensitive, but sometimes the browser not/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turns out JQuery's [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) uses the new javascript method [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) if the browser supports it.  This method is case-insensitive on quirks-mode pages, and case-sensitive on non-quirksmode (aka standards-compliant) pages.  Sure, it's usually obvious that the cases are different, but when the text is stuck in the middle of a long, complex selector it was hard to see.  Apparently there are lots of case-sensitive differences between standards and quirks to watch out for.

Moral of the story: match case of *everything* in your HTML (element names, CSS classes, etc.) because you never know when a change to a browser or standard or library might invalidate your assumption about case-insensitivity.