# Show/Hide Multiple Div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to add another class to this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.carlocation').hide();
      $('#parking-options').change(function() {
        $('.carlocation').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
    });
</script>
```

I am fine with the same ID displaying this classes, I am just unsure about how to add another class to this script. As `'.carlocation' , '.insertclass' or '.carlocation .insertclass'` does nothing but break the script.

Thanks!

EDIT - The rest of the markup.

I would like .carlocation and .car-position to start off as two hidden divs but in the first drop down when "Self parking" is selected that the other two selections display.

```
<li>
                    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Parking Method:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-15" id="parking-options" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="d" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
                       <option value="">Select One</option>
                       <option value="self">Self Parking</option>
                       <option value="auto">Valet Parking</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div id="self" class="carlocation">
                    <h1>Enter Car Location:</h1>
                    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Floor:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-15" id="location-floor" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="d" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
                       <option value="">Floor Select</option>
                       <option value="f1">F1</option>
                       <option value="f2">F2</option>
                       <option value="f3">F3</option>
                       <option value="f4">F4</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div id="self" class="car-position">
                <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Row:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-15" id="position-row" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="d" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
                       <option value="">Row Select</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4</option>
                       <option value="5">5</option>
                       <option value="6">6</option>
                       <option value="7">7</option>
                </select>
                <li>
```

Comment: maybe have a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector

Comment: @shayward The question is a bit confusing. Can you show us your markup, and maybe tell us what effect you want to achieve?

Comment: added the rest of the markup. Im using Jquery Mobile hence all the extra tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide your elements with CSS:

```
.carlocation, .car-position {
    display: none;
}
```

Remove the repeated "self" id from both of the divs, and instead add the "self" value to the class attribute on both:

```
<li>
    <div class="self carlocation">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="self car-position">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</li>
```

*Side Note:* Your second div was missing its closing tag.

Then bind to the change event of the form:

```
$("#parking-options").on("change", function(){
    $("div.self").toggle( $(this).val() === "self" );
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

This bases the visibility of all `.self` divs on the value of the select being "self". If "self" is selected, all `div.self` items will become visible. Otherwise, they become hidden.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/5KJV5/

Or you could slide them into view:

```
$("#parking-options").on("change", function(){
    $(this).val() === "self"
        ? $("div.self").slideDown()
        : $("div.self").slideUp();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/5KJV5/2/

Comment: Its two elements one has the class carlocation and the other will be .insertclass. 

I tried that method but for some reason does not work. But when I leave out the insertClass section the script works perfectly fine.\

Comment: Yes and the one selector will activate both

Comment: @shayward You can't re-use ID values. And you aren't closing your `.car-position` div either. Please post the rest of your markup, and I'll work on it within http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @shayward I've completed a working fiddle. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, was really driving me nuts. Your code is definitely alot simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector can interact with multiple classes (or any other elements) by making a comma separated list within the quotes of the selector, in other words:

```
$('.carlocation, .insertclass, .anotherclass').hide();
```

Edit: Note that case sensitivity can be an issue in some cases, so '.insertclass' is not always the same as '.insertClass' - see [JQuery class selectors like $(.someClass) are case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580029/jquery-class-selectors-like-someclass-are-case-sensitive) for more.

It looks like you might have gotten hung up initially by not having all of your selectors in the same quotes.  Having a space between classes as in `'.carlocation .insertclass'` is actually saying "select an element with the class "insertclass" that is a *child* of an element with class "carlocation"

If you are going to be interacting with the same set of elements more than once, you can optimize your code by assinging them to a variable:

```
var $myselection = $('.carlocation, .insertclass, .anotherclass');
```

(note that putting the '$' in the variable name just helps remind you that it's a jQuery object, you could name it whatever you want).

You can now use any of the normal jQuery methods on $myselection:

```
$myselection.hide();
$myselection.show();
```

or use it later (so long as the variable is accessible within the scope that you're looking for it, which wouldn't be a problem in your initial example).

Comment: To expand on these points, in CSS selectors (and in jQuery selectors) a comma is considered an "or" and not leaving a space is considered an "and".

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple selectors try this-

```
$("selector1,selector2")
```

It will definetly work.
For more information visit [jQuery selectors reference.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)