# Changing label text from dropdown list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I can't seem to get this to fire.. or indeed change the labels text.  Can anyone offer any advise?
The alert is there just because I was testing to see whether or not the event was actually firing.. which it doesn't seem to be.  The only other piece of information is that this is a form within a fancybox iframe.  I'm not even certain I have the code right to change the text, but that's the second issue really.. right now I can't get the event to fire.

Code is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPUom" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm"></asp:DropDownList>



<asp:Label ID="lblpuom" ccclass="col-xs-2 control-label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ddlPUom').change(function () {
        alert("did this fire?");
        var lbltext = doc.getElementById("ddlPUom");
        var lblPUOM = doc.getElementById("lblpuom");
        lblPUOM.lbltext = lbltext.innerhtml;
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for all the comments.. you steered me in the right directions.  In the end I changed the labels to standard `<label></label>` which worked with the above code and made a document.ready function to update from the dropdowns which are set from the code behind..

Comment: Did you set `document` to `var doc = `?

Comment: can you include a snippet of the HTML of the label?

Comment: Also please show us your HTML. And `innerhtml !== innerHTML`

Comment: I'm guessing that `ddlPUom` is a server side control with a `runat="server"` & you need to handle that differently. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227170/accessing-asp-net-controls-using-jquery-all-options/20227176#20227176)

Comment: possible duplicate ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227170/accessing-asp-net-controls-using-jquery-all-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that since `ddlPUom` is a server side control, the id changes when it is rendered in DOM. The page info and control info gets prepended and becomes something like this `ctl00_Main_ddlPUom`

Use

`$('[id$=ddlPUom]').change(function () { // id which ends with the text 'ddlPUom'`

or

`$('[id*=ddlPUom]').change(function () { // id which contains the text 'ddlPUom'`

But there are several other ways here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/489512

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You were all on the right lines.  There also was really no need for the labels to be runat server as I could set them to pick up the correct values from the drop down list which were initially set from the code behind.  So in the end set a document.ready function to set the labels and then .change to change them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct enough to have your alert execute. Maybe the id of your control is not actually set to ddlPUom. It is sometimes case sensitive. See this post about the case sensitivity [JQuery class selectors like $(.someClass) are case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580029/jquery-class-selectors-like-someclass-are-case-sensitive)

Also check the error console in your browser to see if any javascript errors are thrown. 
Firefox : Tools > Web Developer > Error Console
Chrome: right click on the page and select inspect element, click Console in the window that appears.

Now that you added the html - the code below should get the event to fire.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('#<%=ddlPUom.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            alert("did this fire?");
    }
});
```

Comment: the drawback with ClientID is that you cannot write this code in external script files.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ddlPUom').change(function () {
        alert("did this fire?");
        var lbltext = doc.getElementById("<%=ddlPUom.ClientID%>");
        var lblPUOM = doc.getElementById("<%=lblpuom.ClientID%>");
        lblPUOM.lbltext = lbltext.innerhtml;
    });
</script>
```

You might need to add the ClientID portion as well to your drop down list.

Comment: the drawback with `ClientID` is that you cannot write this code in external script files.