# hidden div won't show onhover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Why is my hover function not working?

```js
$("#staff").on("hover", function() {
  $("#staffdn").show();
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffd3d9;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #ffd3d9;
}
#staffdn {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffd3d9;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ffd3d9;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/home.png"></a></li>
    <li><img id="Staff" src="Images/Nav_head/fourms.png"></li>
    <li><a href="Fourms.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/fourms.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/about.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/Nav_head/Games.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="staffdn">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="Staff-memebers.png"></li>
    <li><img src="commands.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you look at hover in the jQuery docs https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @Jacksont It is the visibility that causes the issue.

Comment: Also, selectors are case-sensitive ([on standards-compliant pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580029/jquery-class-selectors-like-someclass-are-case-sensitive#answer-2580031)). So, `$("#staff")` won't necessarily select `<img id="Staff">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- Not use `visibility: hidden`, instead use `display: none` at the load time.
- Hide while loading the page.
- Use `hover` as a function and not as an `event`.
- Put all scripts inside `$(document).ready()` to run on DOM Loaded elements.
- And change the CSS to: `left: 80px; top: 60px;`.

This should work:

```
$(function () {
  $("#staffdn").hide();
  $("#Staff").hover(function() {
    $("#staffdn").show();
  }, function () {
    $("#staffdn").hide();
  });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#staffdn").show();
  $("#Staff").hover(function() {
    $("#staffdn").show();
  }, function () {
    $("#staffdn").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffd3d9;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #ffd3d9;
}
#staffdn {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffd3d9;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ffd3d9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/home.png"></a></li>
    <li><img id="Staff" src="Images/Nav_head/fourms.png"></li>
    <li><a href="Fourms.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/fourms.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html"><img src="Images/Nav_head/about.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/Nav_head/Games.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="staffdn">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="Staff-memebers.png"></li>
    <li><img src="commands.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be find to define `display:none` in the CSS. The issue is that jQuery's `show()` and `hide()`  do not manipulate `visibility`.

Comment: @showdev Had issues with `visibility`, that's the reason I have asked the OP not to use it. What's the best way then?

Comment: Your answer is fine. I just don't see the purpose of "at the load time", "Not define the hide styles in CSS", or "Hide while loading the page". Hiding the element with CSS works, too, as [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/qeh6wy9k/). Also, I wanted to add some explanation of why `visibility` doesn't work here.

Comment: @showdev I had problems when I had used `div {display: none;}` and then at first, if I do `$("div").toggle()`, it won't happen. Okay, now I get it. This explicitly shows `.show()`. Toggle won't happen.

Comment: @showdev I have updated my answer correctly. Can you check? You are awesome buddy. `:D`