# after dom loaded textbox value is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, dom

This is strange. My **.val()** and **.html()** is always undefined although i am using it after everything is loaded on page. also, **.text()** is empty.

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="lblDir" style="width:auto">Scripts Directory Path: <input type="text" id="txturl"></label>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div id="grid" style="border:dashed"></div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <input id="btnRun" type="button" value="Run Scripts" style="margin:5px" />
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="result"></label>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#btnRun").kendoButton();
    $("#btnRun").on("click", function (e) {
        alert($('#txtUrl').text());
    });
});
```

**Things i have tried**
1. putting script tag before div tag
2. adding onclick function in button html

```
<input id="btnRun" type="button" value="Run Scripts" onclick="onInstall();" style="margin:5px" />
```

Result is the same

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Your id on the input is `txturl` but in jquery you are using `#txtUrl` it should be `#txturl`. Also if you want to get the value of the input use `$('#txturl').val()`

Comment: thanks Carsten sometimes i cant see simple things :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the id in HTML markup and id value in script same. And the id value is case sensitive.

In your html markup the id of input type is "txturl" but in js it is "txtUrl". Make both either "txturl" or "txtUrl" and then it should work fine.

Comment: An `input` element uses `.val()`, not `.text()`. :)

Answer (score 3):

As [@Carsten Løvbo Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943218/carsten-l%c3%b8vbo-andersen) mentioned, you need to use `$('#txturl').val()` instead of `$('#txtUrl').text()` because:

- `#txtUrl` doesn't exist. [CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive) and [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580029/jquery-class-selectors-like-someclass-are-case-sensitive) selectors are often case sensetive. (Case-insenstivity is not very well supported.)
- `input` elements don't have `.text()`, but rather [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnRun").on("click", function (e) {
        alert($('#txturl').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-md-12">
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="lblDir" style="width:auto">Scripts Directory Path: <input type="text" id="txturl"></label>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div id="grid" style="border:dashed"></div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <input id="btnRun" type="button" value="Run Scripts" style="margin:5px" />
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="result"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the honor, but i'm happy with letting your answer stay, it's well documented. +1

Comment: @Chris Thanks, i had tried .val() previously and even that didn't work. Kousik pointed rightly that I didn't notice txtUrl was upper case :( so STUPID of me...but your point also stands valid :)